# Java applet trouble, really simple

Tags: java, html, applet

I just started learning Java and I encountered some problems with the  tag in HTML. Actually I think it's because of the attribute classid, I think I'm not using it correctly. I had some experience with HTML/CSS/Javacript/PHP some time ago so I can say that I can manage those.

I have this Java code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class app2 extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("This is an applet",50,50);
    }
}
```

And I have this in HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> First applet </title>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <object codetype="application/java" 
            classid="java:app2.class"
            width="300" height="150" ></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both app2.class and the html file are in the same folder, but when I open the HTML file it doesn't show anything. Using the deprecated tag,  works though. Could you please tell me what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the object tag incorrectly. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html) link for more information on embedding applets in html pages.